# C# Cmd Process Won't Work With Spaces

Tags: c#, cmd

I am opening cmd.exe from my application and navigating it to a file but the problem is that if the file path has spaces in it, it won't go there.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & cd C:\Temp Folder");
```

Instead for looking of Temp Folder, it will only look for temp I guess.

One way is to wrap the path with " " but I can't do it in a string. (tried ' ')

Another way is to loop through the path, find spaces and replace them with something, but I don't know with what.

I could use some help with either of this ways (if you have a better one, that's great)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\` in the string needs to be escaped and you need to include folder names with space in double quotes.

Try

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & cd C:\""Temp Folder""");
```

or

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & cd C:\\\"Temp Folder\"");
```

Comment: Why not include the C:\? Like so: `Process.Start("cmd.exe", @"/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & cd \"C:\Temp Folder\"");`

Comment: Nope, it asks me : C:\Temp Folder\*, Are you sure (Y/N)? When you put that @ there, it's ignoring /C /C Y /N /D Y /T. But yeah, it does navigate to it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an escape character **`\`** for special characters. So, to escape the " , use **`\"`**